# What regression diagnostics should I perform for an ordered probit?

Tags: outliers, multicollinearity, diagnostic, variance-inflation-factor, ordered-probit

Currently I have done the following diagnostics with the

- linktest
- multicollinearity with vif
- the parallel lines assumption with lr test of the oprobit and goprobit.

I have seen that I may have to test for influential outliers, but I don't know how to do this for the ordered probit.